# Multiple selection dates in calender

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar

I has to display the calender in that user can able select the multiple dates .once date is selected then the image must have to change,Like that how many dates user selected those date selected image must be change.I am displaying the image in below what exactly i need,

[image]

so,check the image and give the idea to slove this problem or provide links related to it.Waiting for your answer.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/occalendar  see this control it might help you

Comment: @Romance Did U find any solution?